# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') ReactChartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {vote} from '../store/actions';
import BarChart from "../services/BarChart";
import {color} from '../services/color'


const Poll = ({poll, vote}) => {

    const answers = poll.candidates && poll.candidates.map(candidate => (
        <button onClick={() => vote(poll._id, {answer: candidate.candidate})} key={candidate._id}> {candidate.candidate} </button>
    ));

   const data = {
        labels: poll.candidates.map(candidate => candidate.candidate),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: poll.position,
                backgroundColor: poll.candidates.map(candidate => color()),
                borderColor: '#323643',
                data: poll.candidates.map(candidate => candidate.votes)
            }
        ]
   }
    

        
    return <div>
        <h3>{poll.position}</h3>
        <div>{answers}</div>
        <BarChart chartData={data} />
    </div>
};


export default connect(store => ({
    poll: store.currentPoll
}),{vote},)(Poll);
```

I'm trying to graph a chart using data maping. I don't know what should be the correct syntax here. Image error link below.

Error:

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjPWG.png)
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00hz9.png)

Comment: If the error is that `poll.candidates` doesn't exist, check that the property exists on the object before trying to do stuff with the property

Answer (score 0):

This means that `poll.candidates` is not an array. You can add optional chaining to prevent the error such as `poll?.candidates?.map(...)`, but that won't render your information. You need to find why `candidates` is undefined.

Comment: in fact it means that `poll.candidates` is exactly `undefined` - true that's not an array, but the error is quite specific :p